# "Crysis" vs. "Crisis"

Tags: word-usage, spelling

I remember "Crysis" was a common word in textbooks when I was in school, but "Crysis" has made way for "Crisis" in lots of articles I have read recently.

Has "Crisis" really gained popularity? Any preference in AmE or BrE or International English?

Comment: Crysis is not an English word (or a very uncommon one) - just to be sure I checked several online dictionaries and none of them listed it. Crisis on the other hand is a very common word.

Comment: Crysis is a series of video games - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crysis_(series) & not an Eng word otherwise, afaik.

Comment: "Crisis ... is a very common word." All too common.

Comment: I knew that. That's one of my favorite video games. However, The funny thing is after I played that game I found out "crisis" was all too common. @Tetsujin

Comment: I've never heard of Crysis outside the game context; crisis, on the other hand gets a mention on just about every newspaper front page at least once a week ;-)

Comment: Haha, seems Crysis couldn't pose a real threat to Crisis :-) @Tetsujin

Comment: I realized my last comment sounded more sarcastic than sincere. I'm really interested to see "crysis" used in a context other than the video game. If you had asked me before I read this question, I would have thought it was a completely made up word.

Comment: No worry. I didn't take that as scorn at all. I guess it was my middle school textbook. Perhaps I didn't remember correctly. I'll let you know when I find it out. :-) @ColleenV

Comment: It's not helpful that "crysis" seems to have made it's way into some spell checkers as well, my Word document did not pick it up as wrong, which it certainly is (especially since it was not capitalized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since generic terms cannot be trademarked, businesses at least in the US have for a long time intentionally misspelled common words.  It can also be done for marketing or artistic reasons to impart a mysterious or esoteric quality to an otherwise standard word.

A Google search confirms *crisis* derives from Greek - and it's been an "i" for a long time.  The following is excerpted from [that search](https://www.google.com/search?q=crisis+etymology):

> late Middle English (denoting the turning point of a disease): medical
> Latin, from Greek *krisis* ‘decision,’ from *krinein* ‘decide.’ The
> general sense ‘decisive point’ dates from the early 17th century.
> <sup>[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=crisis+etymology)</sup>